FastHTML: failing to install with pip
Running Zed 0.146.5 on macOS Sonoma 14.5.
When trying to install the package "python-fasthtml" with pip with the following line:
pip install python-fasthtml

and importing with:
from fasthtml.common import *

I receive the traceback:
File "/Users/********/Documents/fastHTML/index.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fasthtml.common import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fasthtml'

When I re-run the pip install command, all the dependencies appeared to be installed along with the package, and it installed them on the first time I ran the command as well. When I try to install with conda(conda install conda-forge::python-fasthtml), it appears to install the package, but the error persists. I've also tried Homebrew(brew install python-fasthtml), but it cannot find the package. Any help?

You forgot to mention your python version?

Also what is the output of running pip show python-fasthtml?

I am facing the exact same issue on Sonoma 14.6.1. The package is installed. But I still get the Module not found error. Python version is 3.12.3

I had the same issue and essentially the same setup/environment.
What ended up working for me was closing Zed, installing Sequoia 15.1 Beta and running pip install python-fasthtml again.
This time it worked no problem. Hopefully that helps.
Edit 0
When attempting to build another fasthtml app I ran into the same problem. After talking to folks on the fast.ai discord server I learned to use miniconda to install all dependencies of each python script instead of installing them globally. After 1) creating a new virtual environment for my script and 2) installing the dependencies in that environment the problem was resolved.
If you are new to miniconda there are lots of instructive tutorials on YouTube.
